# How to get data from a double? Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, double

Yesterday I used some code that worked perfectly fine for me, today I tried using it and it isn't doing the same job it did previously. I am unsure why as I made no changes before running it again.
The code is:

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.txt*','MultiSelect','on');

numfiles = size(FileName,2);

for ii = 1:numfiles
    FileName{ii};

    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii});

    fid = fopen(entirefile);

    tline = fgets(fid);
    while ischar(tline)

        parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');

        if numel(parts{1}) > 0
            A = [ A ; parts{:}' ];
        end
        tline = fgets(fid);
    end

    fclose(fid);

end  

B = A(1:end)
```

When I used it yesterday, `B = A(1:end)` displayed all the data from the files I wished to upload them from, but now its displays the data in binary form, for example:

```
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
[ 1x11 double]
```

Here Is an example of the txt file:

> dark_compensate;1
>   dark_compensate_value_1;0
>   dark_compensate_value_2;0
>   dark_compensate_value_3;0
>   monitor pixel_0;0
>   monitor pixel_1;0
>   monitor pixel_2;0
>   monitor pixel_3;0
>   monitor pixel_4;0
>   monitor pixel_5;0
>   vertical_select_flag;0
>   vertical_line3;63
>   vertical_line4;63
>   vertical_line3_wv;390
>   vertical_line4_wv;390
>   vertical_line_flag;0
>   vertical_line_ratio;0
>   laser_wavelength;0
>   laser_powerlevel;0
>   overlay_js;0
>   Relative Intensity Correction Flag;0
>   Pixel;Wavelength;Wavenumber;Raman Shift;Dark;Reference;Raw data #1;Dark Subtracted #1;%TR #1;Absorbance #1;Irradiance (lumen) #1;
>   0;165.98;60247.73;-60247.73;0.0000;65535.0000;1542.0000;256.7222;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   1;166.38;60103.59;-60103.59;0.0000;65535.0000;1027.0000;-258.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   2;166.78;59960.14;-59960.14;0.0000;65535.0000;357.0000;-928.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   3;167.18;59817.38;-59817.38;0.0000;65535.0000;1281.0000;-4.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   4;167.57;59675.31;-59675.31;0.0000;65535.0000;1229.0000;-56.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   5;167.97;59533.90;-59533.90;0.0000;65535.0000;1210.0000;-75.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   6;168.37;59393.17;-59393.17;0.0000;65535.0000;1235.0000;-50.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   7;168.77;59253.11;-59253.11;0.0000;65535.0000;1274.0000;-11.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   8;169.17;59113.71;-59113.71;0.0000;65535.0000;1265.0000;-20.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   9;169.56;58974.97;-58974.97;0.0000;65535.0000;1198.0000;-87.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   10;169.96;58836.88;-58836.88;0.0000;65535.0000;1276.0000;-9.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;
>   11;170.36;58699.44;-58699.44;0.0000;65535.0000;1285.0000;-0.2778;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;

The loop works so that it only imports the numeric data from the file.
Can anybody suggest why this could be the case? Or how to get the data from the  `[ 1x11 double]`?

Comment: Can you provide example of your text file or how the date looks like?

Comment: Yes sure I'll edit the question and add it in. @Marcin

Comment: The symptoms you report are consistent with your code having (unbeknownst to you) dependencies on variables (and possibly other stuff such as session options) in the interactive workspace.  Yesterday those dependencies were satisfied, today they're not.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thank you for that feedback, have you any tips on how this can be avoided? The size of `A` can vary from use to use of the programme so I don't think preallocating the array is a good option.

Comment: Is the issue that `A` is actually a cell array (confirm with [`iscell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html)) and you don't want it to be and/or want to display the contents?

Comment: @horchler I want to display the contents and use them, soon after posting this question without any change it was working as it did before. However now when I run the code I get an error relating to A saying: `Undefined function or variable 'A'. Error in multiselect (line 16). A = [ A ; parts{:}' ];` I may just have to look into changing this code completely

Comment: I've found if I declare A as: `A = [];` between `fid = fopen(entirefile);`and `tline = fgets(fid);` it gives the data from the last file but not the other selected files as it overwrites them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found your issue. the issue is with `%f` in this line:

`parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');`

As seen in the documentation, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec), you're only pulling out the double-formatted data. Change `%f` to `%s`, and you should be good.

Comment: This will convert the numeric data to a string. I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP wants and what the actual issue is. Also, other changes will likely be needed in order to store the strings in `A`.